# How can I apply conditional thread safety upon operation?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, thread-safety, critical-section

Consider you have a shared memory (List) which will serve as the "critic section".
Now, consider you that you always have items in the list for these scenarios and you want that your system will behave this way:

1. Thread1 get some item from the list, in the very same time Thread2 wants to add item to the list. Allow this scenario( in assumption I will take first item from begining and insert the new item in the end of the list - in the SAME TIME!).
2. Thread1 wants to get an item and in the same time Thread2 wants to get an item too.
   This should fail.

THANKS

Comment: What's the point here?  Are you talking about doing this somehow _without_ using the `synchronized` keyword or a concurrent collection?

Comment: have you checked `CopyOnWriteArrayList` functionality?

Comment: The point is to be like half concurrent depending on the situation 1 or 2.  
2 should be Thread safe like, 1 not, and implementing it in the same data structure, personally I can't see away of doing it, but just wanted to hear some experts advice

Comment: @Quoi: I'm not familiar with that, do you think it is suitable?

Comment: you need granular locking which provides `concurrenthashmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to wrap your List in a class that proxies or overrides the get and add methods.

That way, you can use an explicit `Lock` on the `add` method, so that only one thread can add at any given time.

See for instance:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

You could do this either by extending a `List` implementation, and overriding the `add` and `get` methods (or all relevant methods), or by using composition instead of inheritance, having a proxy class that forwards the calls to the list, but decorates the `add` and `get` with the explicit obtaining of the Lock.

A very simple example would be something like:

```
public class SharedMemory<K> {

private final List<K> memoryList;
private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public SharedMemory() {
    memoryList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void storeItem(K item) {
    memoryList.add(item);
}

public K getItem(int pos){
    lock.lock();
    try{
        return memoryList.get(pos);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it considered as granular locking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... the locking here can be as granular as you need it to be, just fine tune it to lock only the specific blocks of code that need "protection."

Comment: @JavaSa granularity of locking simply refers to how large or small the code sections you're locking are.  For example, if you just apply one global lock that is very course granularity.  However, if you lock on only one or two operations per method, that is very fine granularity.